# Is there ever a reason to use "::template"?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

You can use the `template` keyword when getting a template name from a global namespace:

```c++
template <class T> void function_template();

template <class T>
void h()
{
    ::template function_template<T>();
}

int main() { h<int>(); }
```

But this code can compile without it. What are the situations in which one might want to do this?

Comment: @KerrekSB But `function_template` is a member of the *global namespace* and this code can compile without it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you mean specifically the global version - never mind then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of one place, but I hardly think it would be common:

```
#include <iostream>

// simpile function template
template<class T>
void function_template(T)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

// overload (NOT specialized)
void function_template(int value)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    function_template(0);               // calls overload
    ::function_template(0);             // calls overload
    ::template function_template(0);    // calls template, deduces T
}
```

**Output**

```
void function_template(int)
void function_template(int)
void function_template(T) [T = int]
```

I was going to stuff some of this in an anonymous namespace to actually bring non-trivial meaning to `::` but this seems to be sufficient so I left it out.

Comment: [temp.names]/p5 says "A name prefixed by the keyword `template` shall be a *template-id* or the name shall refer to a class template." `::template function_template` is neither, so it should be ill-formed.